# Chrome extension to show an alert on certain websites

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I'm looking for an extension that will allow me to display a popup alert message on the webpage, for example if I'm on Google.com there would be a message "You're on Google, please continue to use this search engine as your privacy is not compromised" Is there anything like this ?

Comment: Make one yourself?  Users scripts are pretty easy to make with Tampermonkey.  http://tampermonkey.net/

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from the question, but I assume you are looking for some sort of phishing prevention?

If so, here is a possible chrome plugin.  http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2012/11/19/chrome-version-of-netcraft-anti-phishing-extension-available.html